# phonegap (2.7) inappbrowser UTF8 support

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

i'm writing a android apps with phonegap and need inappbrowser to display certain contents, so i write some testing code

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>

    <html>

      <head>
        <title>Hello World</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.7.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.3.2.css" /> 
        <script src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.mobile-1.3.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
        </script>
        <style>
        #footer {
          position:fixed;
          bottom:0;
          width:100%;
        }
        </style>   
      </head>

    <body>

      <div data-role="page" id="page_dashboard">

          <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="scripts/dashboard.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
                var ref = window.open('http://apache.org','_blank','location=yes, enableViewportScale=yes');
                ref

.addEventListener('loadstart', function() { alert(event.url); });
      </script>
```

[image]

After i clicked the button, the strange code will convert to the valid text. That is "Alert" box to prompt "undefined" text.

Problems:
Why the text can't be displayed?
Why there is a alert box when the apps start?

Comment: seems uft8 problem, removed    <meta charset="utf-8"/> will work. But my apps need display text other than english, how to solve this problem?

Comment: problem fixed by setting->project encoding in android studio